# return logs from map_async multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, neo4j, multiprocessing, azure-databricks

I am trying to test a neo4j graph and this the simplified case where everything goes well and returns a list of runtimes. However my real purpose is to actually return a dict with some logs like PID , date , query response ... like if Ic could append q_resp = {"qid":q,"resp":qtest ,"avg_runtime":averageruntime ,"Date":...}... but it seems like I cannot return other than single valued function and I tried to create global variable to share the appended logs but in vain . any not too complex idea to get around this ?

by the way only map_async from pool multiprocessing worked for me , map did not do it nor other libs like asyncio maybe because I am working from azure databricks (but I could be totally wrong).

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

qlist = ["Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100","Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100","Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100","Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100","Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100","Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100", "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100" , "Match (n:person) RETURN n LIMIT 9300" ,"Match (n:company) RETURN n LIMIT 2" ,"Match (n:compound) RETURN n LIMIT 1"]

conn = new_connex(0) #instatiate neo4j connector
def singleq_test(q: str ):
    ar = []
    ntest = 5
    #time.sleep(ti)
    print("inside singleq")
    for n in range(ntest):
        starttime = time.time()
        qtest = conn.query(q) #getting response 
        runtime = time.time()-starttime
        ar.append(runtime)
    #
    averageruntime = sum(ar)/ntest
    return averageruntime

def qlist_test(ql: list ):
    
    with Pool() as po:
        print("inside pool")
        res = po.map_async(singleq_test,ql)
        qltimes = res.get(timeout=20)
        #print(qltimes)

    return qltimes
qlist_test(qlist)
```

Comment: `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` is implemented equivalently to calling `map_sync` followed by `get()` on the returned `AsyncResult` instance. The only difference between this and what you are doing is passing a timeout value to `get`. If the timeout does occur, it will raise an exception that you are not prepared to catch. So I am having difficulty in understanding how using `map_async` works for you but `map` does not.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would code the program to:

1. have the worker function, `singleq_test`, return both the average running time and, for example, the results of the query
2. show how to assign to each pool process its own connection in case a single connection cannot be used across processes
3. make the program runnable on platforms that use either the *spawn* method (e.g. Windows) or *fork* method (e.g. Linux) for starting new child processes

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError

def init_pool_processes():
    global conn
    conn = new_connex(0) #instatiate neo4j connector

def singleq_test(q: str):
    ar = []
    ntest = 5
    #time.sleep(ti)
    print("inside singleq")
    for n in range(ntest):
        starttime = time.time()
        qtest = conn.query(q) #getting response 
        runtime = time.time()-starttime
        ar.append(runtime)
    #
    averageruntime = sum(ar)/ntest
    # return average runtime and query results as a tuple:
    return (averageruntime, qtest)

def qlist_test(ql: list):
    
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes) as po:
        print("inside pool")
        res = po.map_async(singleq_test, ql)
        try:
            # Get list of tuples:
            tpls = res.get(timeout=20)
            for tpl in tpls:
                # Unpack each tuple:
                averageruntime, qtest = tuple
                print(averageruntime, qtest)
        except TimeoutError:
            print('map_async timed out')
            qltimes = []
            
    return qltimes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qlist = [
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:person) RETURN n LIMIT 9300",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n LIMIT 2" ,
        "Match (n:compound) RETURN n LIMIT 1"
        ]
    qlist_test(qlist)
```

If a single connection *can* be shared among all processes, then:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError

def init_pool_processes(the_connection):
    global conn
    conn = the_connection

def singleq_test(q: str):
    ar = []
    ntest = 5
    #time.sleep(ti)
    print("inside singleq")
    for n in range(ntest):
        starttime = time.time()
        qtest = conn.query(q) #getting response 
        runtime = time.time()-starttime
        ar.append(runtime)
    #
    averageruntime = sum(ar)/ntest
    # return average runtime and query results as a tuple:
    return (averageruntime, qtest)

def qlist_test(ql: list):
    
    conn = new_connex(0) #instatiate neo4j connector
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(conn,)) as po:
        print("inside pool")
        res = po.map_async(singleq_test, ql)
        try:
            # Get list of tuples:
            tpls = res.get(timeout=20)
            for tpl in tpls:
                # Unpack each tuple:
                averageruntime, qtest = tuple
                print(averageruntime, qtest)
        except TimeoutError:
            print('map_async timed out')
            qltimes = []
            
    return qltimes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qlist = [
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n.country_code LIMIT 100",
        "Match (n:person) RETURN n LIMIT 9300",
        "Match (n:company) RETURN n LIMIT 2" ,
        "Match (n:compound) RETURN n LIMIT 1"
        ]
    qlist_test(qlist)
```

**Note**

Since the work being performed by `singleq_test` is primarily database access, I would think that a multithreading pool would work just as well if not better -- at least it is something to try. The only change you need to make is:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool, TimeoutError
```

Now the question becomes whether a single connection can be shared among multiple *threads* running in the same process or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

Simplest is that you can return pretty much anything from `simpleq_test`.  Rather than having it return just a single value, it can return a result and values to put into the dictionary.  You would then have:

```
for qltime, dictionary_stuff in res.get(timeout=20):
    ... append qltime to qltimes...
    do something with the dictionary stuff
```

An alternative is to create a multiprocessing queue.  Your threads can add information to the queue, and your main thread can read items from the thread and handle them however it wants.

changes made to a variable in one process do not affect its value in another process.